# Problema renderizado de Tag Helper en ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

He creado un **tag helper** personalizado pero no me lo renderiza en la vista, básicamente no me traduce el atributo `generate-words` con el contenido que tengo que sacar en pantalla.

Código de mi **tagHelper**:

```
namespace Pract7._4.Extensions.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = "generate-words")]
    public class LoremIpsumTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        [HtmlAttributeName("generate-words")]
        public int Words { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.SuppressOutput();
            output.Content.SetContent(GetWords());
        }

        private string GetWords()
        {
            string resultGenerated = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < Words; i++)
            {
                var randomizer = new Randomizer();
                resultGenerated = " " + randomizer.Next();
            }
            return resultGenerated;
        }
    }
}
```

Código de mi **_ViewImports.csHtml**:

```
@using Pract7._4
@using Pract7._4.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Pract7._4.Extensions.TagHelpers
```

Código de la **vista** donde pongo el atributo:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" generate-words="6"></div>
```

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo soluciono esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está está localizado en dos puntos:

**1** - En primer lugar, estás definiendo mal la directiva `@addTagHelper` en el archivo `_ViewImports.csHtml`.

El formato correcto para `@addTagHelper` es:

```
@addTagHelper [NAMESPACE_DEL_TAG_HELPER], [NOMBRE_DEL_ENSAMBLADO]
```

Así que debes definirlo de la siguiente manera:

```
@addTagHelper Pract7._4.Extensions.TagHelpers.*, Pract7
```

Donde `Pract7._4.Extensions.TagHelpers.*` hace referencia a **todos los TagHelpers** de la **carpeta** `TagHelpers`, y **`Pract7`** es en **nombre del ensamblado (dll)** de tu aplicación ASP.NET Core.

**2** - Por otra parte, debes eliminar la línea **`output.SuppressOutput();`** ya que lo que está haciendo es **generar una salida vacía** en tu TagHelper.